# Corona sdk swap image files

Tags: image, swap, coronasdk

### Is there a simple way to swap an image that is assigned to a body? Example code:

```
local cat = display.newImage( "catright.png",100, 375 ); 
physics.addBody( cat, { density=0.9, friction=5, bounce=0 } );
```

### cat.name = "cat";

At certain times, I need to swap catright.png for catleft.png.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but you can use a single .png file to use as a sprite sheet instead. Then you can add two sequences named as "catright" and "catleft", and use them in necessary places.

This link is a good reference point:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/sprite-sheets

Comment: Thanks for the info. I bookmarked the site. I have played around with sprite sheets a little. I did get past my problem by removing the catleft.png when appropriate, and re-initializing it to catright.png. Probably not the best way, but it is fast. I may still replace it with sprites. Thanks again.